# Writing a formula to subtract row value(s) from all column values in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I need help writing an if then statement in R. I need to subtract the values from row 6 from each cell from every column.

If after the subtraction the value is greater than 0, I need the subtracted value reported. If after the substraction the value is less than 0 (negative value), I need the formula to report a 0. I need this done for every column, accross nearly 14,000 columns. I assume I need to use if_else and then a loop to execute? Any help would be hugeley appreciated!!

INPUT

```html
         A     B      C
1     1345     0    100
2     1300    24      3
3       89    25      5
4    19000    90    200
5        0   100     10
6      100     9      7
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```html
           A      B     C
1       1245    0    93
2       1200    15   16
3          0    16    0
4      18900    81  193
5          0    91    3
6        100    9     7
```

Comment: Suppose your datatet is `data`, you can do `data[-nrow(data),] <- sapply(data, function(i)
  ifelse(i - tail(i,1)<0, 0, i - tail(i,1)))[-NROW(data),]`
It is required to share a code example to make the question and the answers more straightful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

input |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(row_number() == 6, ., .-.[6])),
         across(everything(), ~ifelse(. < 0, 0, .)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       A     B     C
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1245     0    93
#> 2  1200    15     0
#> 3     0    16     0
#> 4 18900    81   193
#> 5     0    91     3
#> 6   100     9     7
```

or with base R

```r
apply(input, 2, \(x)ifelse(x == x[6], x, x-x[6])) |>
  apply(2, \(x) ifelse(x < 0, 0, x)) |>
  as.data.frame()
#>       A  B   C
#> 1  1245  0  93
#> 2  1200 15   0
#> 3     0 16   0
#> 4 18900 81 193
#> 5     0 91   3
#> 6   100  9   7
```

EDIT for non-numerics

```r
new_input <- input |>
  mutate(nonNum = "Ahhhh!!")


new_input |>
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(row_number() == 6, ., .-.[6])),
         across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(. < 0, 0, .)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>       A     B     C nonNum 
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1  1245     0    93 Ahhhh!!
#> 2  1200    15     0 Ahhhh!!
#> 3     0    16     0 Ahhhh!!
#> 4 18900    81   193 Ahhhh!!
#> 5     0    91     3 Ahhhh!!
#> 6   100     9     7 Ahhhh!!
```

Comment: Thank you @AndS.  the tidyverse version worked!! In my real data frame I have some non-numeric columns prior to  ABC. Is there is a way to specify within this formula that (for instance), columns 1-5 should be excluded from the calulation? if there is, I would save loads of time.

Comment: Yes, use `where(is.numeric)` instead of `everything()`. See update.